# How to load more than 1 module asynchronously in web pack 2?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, webpack-2

I am trying to split code and async load modules on demand in webpack2. I am able to load one module using

`require.ensure([], function(require) {
            var obj1 = require("./module1");
})`

However, I am unable to load 2 modules say in this case module1 and module2. I could create module12 comprising module1 and module2, but would be great to know if there is a way to load more than 1 module through web pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can you not just do this?—

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
  var obj1 = require("./module1");
  var obj2 = require("./module2");
})
```

Comment: Thanks thesublimeobject for the answer. It works. Somehow, all examples mentioned only one import. This works very well